# Class 'Mage_Easytabs_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: php, magento

Magento is giving this error when I try to go and edit System > Permissions > Roles

Administrator or add a new role.

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Easytabs_Helper_Data' not found in /home/desynerx/public_html/magento3/app/Mage.php on line 547

I have not see this error come-up anywhere else when setting up the site. Is this an issue with the custom theme or one of the 3rd party extensions I have installed?

Anyone have any ideas where to start troubleshooting?

Cheers!

Comment: *"Anyone have any ideas where to start troubleshooting?"* line 547 in Mage.php

Comment: Mage.php Line 547:   self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);

Comment: can you config.xml of easytab extension

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with your 3rd party extention. 
1. If realy dont want that extention disable is in admin > system > configuration >  advanced

2. If you want that extention , make sure your module have helper file in Mage/Easytabs/Helper/Data.php
   If this file not available create it .

After that also you have anyproblem write here.

I am happy to be with magento and magento buddies.

Comment: Thanks Reezaa. I am checking now, the problem is that there are several Extensions installed already  I am not sure which one it is...

Answer (score 0):

Remove Easytabs extention from your system.

Buddy. Pls Dont instal 3rd party extention without reading user review.

Easytabs extention doesnot have a good review.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-tabs-2-0-free-magento-extension.html

Comment: I DIDN'T install it!! I only installed 3 extensions and this was not one of them... never even heard of it.

Comment: In your admin panal, dont you have a extention called Easytabs??? If not go to app/etc/modules folder and delete Mage_Easytabs.xml this will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. But thats what so frustrating.. there is nothing there. No Mage_Easytabs.xml, nothing remotely close.

Answer (score 0):

add the following code

```
<?php
class TM_EasyTabs_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

to
 `app/code/community/TM/EasyTabs/Helper/Data.php` (create one if it doesn't exists)

I hope it might work.

Answer (score 0):

First check the error log in /var/log folder in your magento installation.

There must be some line which will tell you which module is being referenced for easytabs.

Next go to that module's code. Check that there must be some code like this in `app/code/<Package>/Easytabs/etc` folder.

```
<global>
<helpers>
<checkout>
<class>{Package}_Easytabs_Helper</class>
</checkout>
</helpers>
</global>
```

if not, then copy it and paste into config.xml of module

Then check whether there is `app/code//{package}/Easytabs/Helper/Data.php`

and it contains code like this:

```
<?php
class {package}_Easytabs_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{
}
```

If the module was removed or disabled, then check there are some calls to helper functions in your code.

Please let me know your review after checking above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include data helper.so the following code in your Helper/Data.php

```
<?php class Package_Test_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

and in config file you need to have following enteries

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <test>
            <class>Package_Test_Helper</class>
        </test>
    </helpers>
</global>
```